# jQuery - How to select another tr if an input does not match a value

Tags: jquery

As a newbie, I'm trying to pull something off and have gotten stuck.  I'm attempting to select a table row with an id of "fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd" and add a class of "selected" if someone enters a state other than Illinois into an input field with the class of "customer_state_name".  Here's my HTML that doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Basic</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Show the tax info if the shipping state is not Illinois
        $("#customer_state_name").each(function()
        {
            if (!$(this).html() == 'Illinois')
            {
            $("#fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd").addClass("selected");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="#">
    <input name="state" id="customer_state_name" value="" />
    </form>

    <table>
    <tr id="fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd">
    <td>Content here!</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: May I suggest [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), for posting demonstrations? Also, what do you mean by 'select' a table row?

Comment: Hey David...thanks for your response.  I just updated the posting to clarify.  What I meant to do was add a class to the row with the id described above.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right a few concerns.

1. You are using a `.each()` function on an ID.  IDs must be unique within a document, use a class if there are multiple items.
2. You are using `$(this).html()` to get the value of an `<input>` field, use `.val()` instead.
3. The code you have only executes once on entry to the page, you need to make a `.change()` function on the `<input>`s, so that it runs every time the users alters them.
4. You are using `(!a == b)` as your condition, this is not what you intend I think, you should use not-equal `(a != b)`.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".customer_state_name").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 'Illinois') {
      $("#fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd").addClass("fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd");
    } else {
      $("#fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd").removeClass("fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd");
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#">
    <input name="state" class="customer_state_name" value="" />
</form>

<table>
    <tr id="fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd">
        <td>Content here!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Orbling.  One question I didn't address above is what happens if someone decides they want to change the state value later?  How do we in effect remove the class we just added?

Comment: @flinx777 Added an `else` clause that does the opposite.  If the class does not already exist, the `.removeClass()` call will just do nothing.

Comment: Ok...played around with it and got everything to work with your code...thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).val() != 'Illinois') ...
```

The unary negation operator has higher precedence than you think.

Also, there is no reason to `.each()` on `$('#...')`, as only one element with a particular `id` attribute is ever legal within the same document. Either you should be using a CSS class instead, or you could simply:

```
if ($('#customer_state_name').val() != 'Illinois') ...
```

without the outer `.each()` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is already answered, but I wanted to point out that you ought to do something to account for proper-/lower-/upper-casing.  Supposed your user has caps lock on.  Suppose they don't proper case. Suppose they accidentally hit the space bar.  I think this code will work much nicer for your purposes.  It forces proper case and trims the value of the text box.  Also, you want to make sure that the class is removed if the condition "Illinois" isn't met.   Try the following code out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/JhfrB/).

```
$(function() {
  $("#customer_state_name").change(function() {
      var stateName = $(this).val().split(" ");
      var stateProper = new Array();
      for(x in stateName){         
          stateProper.push(stateName[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + stateName[x].substr(1).toLowerCase());
      }
      var stateProper=stateProper.join(" ").trim();
      $(this).val(stateProper);
    if($(this).val() != 'Illinois') {
      $("#fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd").addClass("selected");
    }
      else{
      $("#fc_cart_foot_tax_tbd").removeClass("selected");    
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Without `var x` you are creating and changing a global variable. It's shorter and faster to write `var stateProper = []`. There is no reason to re-var `stateProper` repeatedly.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I understand that I'm creating and changing a global variable.  I don't know where you mean for me to insert "var stateProper = []".  I understand that I don't need to re-var stateProper, but I've gotten into the habit of doing it, because I've come up across a number of array problems which re-varring solves.

Comment: @bozdox ... thank you so much for taking the time to create this.  I'll have to study this a bit more to understand it.  thnx!